# How to provide multiple values at once to a BehaviorSubject

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a function `isChanged` which emits `Observable<Boolean>`. I defined a function which uses the stream like so:

```
Observable<Boolean> myFunc() {
  return isChanged().skip(1).distinctUntilChanged();
}
```

Now, I want to test whether the `skip(1)` works as desired. So I created a `BehaviorSubject<Boolean> subject` as simply:

```
BehaviorSubject<Boolean> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();
```

In my test function, I have (with the proper mocks and initializations):

```
when(isChanged()).thenReturn(subject);
subject.onNext(true);
subject.onNext(false);
myFunc().test().assertValueCount(1);
```

This assertion fails, and the error it provides is that the expected value count is 1, whereas the actual is 0.

The test passes when I remove the `skip()` condition, which makes me realize it's got something to do with the assertion checking only the latest value from the subject.

Not super clear on this, any help would be highly appreciated!

Edit:
The `isChanged()` is actually a placeholder for a custom [switch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat)'s custom function. So, I actually have a mock for that switch (called `switchMock`) and my actual statement is `when(switchMock.isChanged()).thenReturn(subject)`. Not sure if the specifics are needed here. Would be happy to provide additional information, of course!

Comment: need to see more code on how you define isChanged() initialized BehaviorSubject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BehaviorSubject` holds one item, which you overwrote in your tests and then started observing the subject. At this point, the subject will emit its single value which gets dropped by `skip` and thus the test correctly fails with no items. You have to start observing earlier:

```java
when(isChanged()).thenReturn(subject);

TestObserver<Boolean> to = myFunc().test();

subject.onNext(true);
subject.onNext(false);

to.assertValueCount(1);
```